# Draw child views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, viewgroup

I has my own View subclass that does Layout (I call it ViewGallery), my problem is that views that I draw manually wont appear at screen, here's it onDraw method.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    for(Child child : visibleChilds){
        canvas.save();
        canvas.clipRect(child.bounds);
        child.view.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}

private List<Child> visibleChilds = new ArrayList<ViewGallery.Child>();

private static class Child {
    private View view;
    private Rect bounds;

    public Child(View view, Rect rect) {
        this.view = view;
        bounds = rect;
    }
}
```

As far as I know that should draw the inner view in the specified clipped Canvas.

Why the view is still empty?

Also I tried extends ViewGroup so I pass itself as parameter in a Adapter, but default ViewGroup.LayoutParams doesn't has left (or x) properties that I need to handle properly translation of views. But when subclassing it the onDraw never get called and childs still wont appear.

Comment: You need to override dispatchDraw() to draw the children, not onDraw(). You could do it from onDraw() but you'd first need to call setWillNotDraw(false). You should also use ViewGroup.drawChild() to properly draw each child.

Comment: there's no dispatchDraw to override at ViewGroup, i'm trying to use the setWillNotDraw approach. Also, I need to know if the ViewGroup will handle addViews or should I override it too?

Comment: Yes there is a dispatchDraw() method: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#dispatchDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)

Comment: Oh trues.. i mistake while wroting it twice in the class =/ but the view still ins't drawing nothing. I'm not overriding onLayout cause the view has it own height at layouts and it's childs has the same size and can be placed properly inside the component. May i call onMeasure into childs to handle it?

Comment: If you're overriding ViewGroup you must override onLayout() to lay out the children. This means you will likely need to override onMeasure() as well. You should look at FrameLayout as an example.

Comment: I cannot rely on sizes since the more views can be created at runtime while scrolling content. How can I handle that? I'm already calling child.layout(0, 0, measuredWidth, measuredHeight) that are the same value as the Child.bounds that i'm trying to draw. So when dispatchDraw is called, the views ins't attached to any viewgroup but it's still should draw(clippedCanvas) wont it?

Comment: Well, i'm using FrameLayout as example, this does looks like that I should use the addViews from ViewGroup and control it at subclass, and also I doesn't see a way to call assignParent in a child since it's package protected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question properly.
But if you are trying to draw a  view on the canvas, you have to enable the drawing cache, get the bitmap from it and draw that.

example:

```
            // you have to enable setDrawingCacheEnabled, or the getDrawingCache will return null
            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

            // we need to setup how big the view should be..which is exactly as big as the canvas
            view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(canvas.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(canvas.getHeight(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
            // assign the layout values to the textview
             view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());


             mBitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
             canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, x, y, mPaint);
            // disable drawing cache
            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Ofcourse in this instance it'll just be a bitmap of the view drawn on the given location.